# PEP8 inspection in PyCharm not working

Tags: pycharm, pep8

I have recently upgraded to PyCharm and the automated PEP8 inspection stopped working. I have made sure that it's enabled in

```
Preferences ->  Editor ->  Inspection
```

but I still can't see the errors being highlighted within the code. Any idea on what I'm forgetting here?

Comment: Are you in power save mode?

Comment: @Makoto nope, it's disabled

Comment: Are you using remote Python interpreters or something like PyPy or Jython? Do you have at least one local CPython interpreter set up in PyCharm? It is needed for running the pep8.py tool.

Comment: @AndreyVlasovskikh not using remote interpreters. I have /usr/bin/python set up as the project interpreter (2.7.5)

Comment: @AviMeir Check your idea.log file (Help | Show Log in ...) for entries about pep8.